# Email template internationalisation / localisation on play framework 1.x

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm developing an mobile app and using play as our server part and got stuck on the internationalisation / localisation part of emails.
I see that play gets locale from accept language headers, but, in my case, the rest request comes from our Android client and the locale is sent via parameter, not via request header.
My problem is: when I get the internationalised version of email's subject, for example, this is done programatically, so I can send a locale param to getMessage, but, when I use the "send" method from play's Mailer, the txt template uses the headers' information, which doesn't exactly match the locale param passed through the rest service.
I've tried this approach with no luck:

On rest controller:

```
...
request.acceptLanguage().clear();
request.acceptLanguage().add(locale); // locale is the param which contains "en", or "pt" or other languages
...
Mails.passwordRecoverByEmail(locale, user, password);
...
```

My template looks somethings like this (it's a txt):

```
&{'email.passwordRecoverByEmail.hello'} ${user.username},

&{'email.passwordRecoverByEmail.body'} ${newPassword}.

&{'email.passwordRecoverByEmail.body2'}
```

But, I still get the template in english, sending a locale as "pt", for example.

Debugging I saw that the request's acceptLanguage doesn't change after clearing or adding the new locale.

Any clues?

Comment: I've ended up adding the accept-language header on the requests, anyway, I would like to be able to pass a locale to render/send from email, if it were possible...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% it would work in your case but possibly calling `Lang.set(locale)` prior to the email render.